# Modelica electrical delay

Tags: modelica

I am creating model for electrical system (power supply with digital control) in Modelica.

I use Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.PulseVoltage and Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.FixedDelay I want to connect them. 
How to do a mix (interconnect) between Blocks.Nonlinear and Electrical components?

I need to generate pulses to my transistors which are shifted so I decided to use FixedDelay. 
Is there better way to do a delay of pulsing voltage?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: Sync clock and shift registers

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.PulseVoltage` as source you can use `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Pulse` and connect this with `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.FixedDelay` and add finally `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalVoltage` in order to generate an actual voltage out of your delayed pulses. I'm not sure if this is the best solution for the application you have but at least that way you would get delayed voltage pulses :)

/Dietmar/

Comment: Just to elaborate, what this is doing is using the Blocks library to build up a "signal generator" and then feeding that to a SignalVoltage to create and actual voltage difference from the signal.

Note that if you need a voltage for both the reference signal and the delayed signal, you'll need to connect a SignalVoltage block to each of those signals.

Comment: I need to have advanced PWM (pulse width modulator) with different time shape pulses of independent or complementary signals. You need to look at TI, Freescale, Microchip controllers. After simulation I am transferring this behavior to these microcontrollers. I think Modelica does not reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

"For nowadays my solution is"

```
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Ideal.IdealClosingSwitch Switch1 
Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.FixedDelay                Delay1 
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Pulse                       Pulse1 
Modelica.Blocks.Math.RealToBoolean                  Realtoboolean1 

connect(Pulse1.y,Delay1.u) 
connect(Delay1.y,Realtoboolean1.u) 
connect(Realtoboolean1.y, Switch1.control)
```

I am not sure is perfect but it works...

Further I need to add digital control - another challenge

Best regards, 
Peter